# Jquery cookie plugin remove item from multiple items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I work with [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) v 2.2.1 and set multiple value to name like this:

html:

```
<a href="#" id="<?= esc($product->id);?>" class="hvr-bounce-in wishlist">
   <i class="icon-favorite_outline"></i>
</a>
```

js:

```
$('.wishlist').click(function() {     
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    ids = Cookies.get("wishlist")
    if (!ids)
    Cookies.set('wishlist', id)
    else
    Cookies.set('wishlist', ids + "," + id)
});
```

output in cookie is:

```
61,58,95,105
```

Now I need to remove one value from this list like 58. How can I remove it?

Comment: Is it also possible to provide an example list as source code?

Comment: @Reporter: your mean from cookie?

Comment: Yes, so we can get a picture of your "list " structure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)